# Is there a way to use Python to emulate a non visible external monitor, and capture the video data from it?

Tags: android, python, external, monitor, multiple-monitors

Beginning with the end in mind, I am looking into creating an Android app that would act like iDisplay, or AirDisplay.

Both of the aforementioned apps are used on an Android device to act like a secondary screen for a Mac/Windows computer. However, as they both cost $10-$4, I am looking into creating a free version of them, possibly with a few more features, for free.
However, I have been unsuccessful in my attempts to find any libraries for a Python client that acts as an external monitor and grabs the video data from the "unseen" external screen, let alone code examples for anything remotely similar.

(Please note that I understand that I can grab the screen data, and have it mirror the display, but I am attempting to find a way to extend the desktop)

Is there a way to do this in Python? Or should I look into some other languages?
Ultimately, I would prefer it to be cross-platform, but if you can only offer a solution for Windows, Linux or OSX, they are all appreciated.